# HTML List not displaying properly after being saved in SQL Server

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I've been stuck with this problem for a little while now and I have no clue on how to solve it.

So basically, I'm working on an HTML page. In it, there's a list (UL). 
It displays properly in every browser I want.

For some reason, I need to stock the HTML page in a database (Microsoft SQL Server 2008).
When I use it after, everything is displayed properly except for the fact that the dots next to the list items not being present.

It only happens AFTER being taken from SQL but the code generated is the same.
I tried on each browser and it does the same thing on all of those.

By the way, (this should be a big part of the problem) the HTML is rendered in an ASP.net page after being taken out of the database.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be the cause of this ?

Thanks alot !

Comment: The html has to be different after generating the page from what's in the database.  Have you looked at the html that was generated?  You will need to post some code so someone can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: could you please provide the code for inserting and extracting from the db, and the display function as well?

Comment: Mhh I can't really post the code though, but I forgot to say that the HTML is used in an asp page, which must be the cause of the problem. But yes, the generated html is the same as the one saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving code to `VARCHAR` data type column you need to escape the escape characters that you might be passing in. Just like other people mentioned in comments, you need to verify that the code you are passing in, is properly stored and returned from SQL Server. Get the code from SQL Server and put into browser to verify that it is being stored correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I tried this, took the code directly from the DB and put it in a new file, which I opened. It displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured the problem, I first thought it was due to ASP.net or the compatibility, but that wasn't the problem.

It was all due to how my page was organized. The lack of space in the 'divs' made the dots hidden in only a certain modes in IE... I changed the alignment of the text by accident and it solved everything